# why QIterator object behave differently for same folder placed in two different locations?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qtextbrowser

I have a folder inside which i have following folder(s)/file(s)
(Folder in bold)

> 1.**make_file_example**
>
> > 1.1.main.cpp
> >     1.2.MakeFile
> >     1.3.message.cpp
> >     1.4.message.h
>
> 2.makeFileExample.txt
>   3.other_sources.txt
>   4.QTnotes.txt

[I've copy/pasted the same folder in two different locations]
In following images you can clearly see how same folder when placed in different location give different results
[image: image1][image: image2]

the code snippet I've used is as follows:

```
   void MainWindow::on_pushButton_browse_clicked()
{
    ui->textBrowser_filename->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
    ui->textBrowser_filename->setText("");
    QString dir= QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                   "/home",
                                                   QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                   | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    ui->lineEdit_dir->setText(dir);
    QDirIterator it(dir, QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllEntries , QDirIterator::Subdirectories | QDirIterator::FollowSymlinks);
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        QString path=it.fileName();
        ui->textBrowser_filename->append(path);
        it.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't displaying whatever file happens to be the last in the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

the culprit is the `next()` function being called after the path is printed in the `textBrowser_filename` change the while loop as follows:

```
while(it.hasNext())
    {
        it.next();
        QString path=it.fileName();
        ui->textBrowser_filename->append(path);        
    }
```

if the entry is still there, as said by the `hasNext()` function, it must be iterated first.